# Why do we need private variables in Flutter Widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

The question is simple & hard to understand at the same time. Why do I need to mark all my variables in the Statefull Widget as private?

Now when I declare a variable I declare it like private.

```
bool _isOpened = true;
String _currentUserUID;
...
```

But why do I need this? I do not access these variables from other widgets. I do not override. I know my app logic & totally insured in the safety of my code in all widgets.

So why do I need private variables? Is there any impact of using private variables & methods? Maybe performance benefits?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The prefix _ makes the variable private within the  .dart code file you are in. The IDE (or at least VSCode, that I use) will then be able to tell you if you are using the variable or not. It also tells me, as the developer, that I need look no further than the code file that I am working in for changes to this variable.  All important information as far as I am concerned.

The same is true when making methods private with the _ prefix. This is also highly recommended.

However, imho, this question relates to the the use of private variables in general so here is a link to a more general question and a much better set of answers than mine https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143736/why-do-we-need-private-variables